# Getting (void 0) is undefined error in cypress

Tags: reactjs, testing, cypress, end-to-end

I have this test case:

```
before(()=>{
    cy.fixture('example').then(function (data) {
      this.data = data;
    })
    cy.visit("http://127.0.0.1:3000/");
    cy.contains("Connect Wallet").click();
    cy.contains("Metamask").click();
    cy.wait(10000)
    cy.contains("0x352e").click();
    cy.contains("Profile").click();
    cy.wait(10000); // waiting for the profile to completely load
  })

 it.only("Edit User Profile",()=>{
    cy.contains("Edit Profile").click();
    cy.get('[data-testid="name"]').click();
    cy.get('[data-testid="name"]').type(this.data.name);  // getting error on this line
  })
```

I am getting error `(void 0) is undefined` . What am I doing wrong ? Do I need to import any module to use the fixture's data ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the this context, you have to use function. From [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#this-context):

> If you store and access the fixture data using this test context
> object, make sure to use function () { ... } callbacks. Otherwise the
> test engine will NOT have this pointing at the test context.

```js
it.only('Edit User Profile', function () {
  cy.contains('Edit Profile').click()
  cy.get('[data-testid="name"]').click()
  cy.get('[data-testid="name"]').type(this.data.name)
})
```